# Twilio : how to look up conference name?

Tags: twilio

In my app I have multiple users who will use multiple conferences.
I am currently using one telephone number and each user logs in with a client name.
One user invites others to a conference he initiates. He invites them via their client name which is recorded from didReceivePresenceUpdate.

I am struggling for the callee to get to know the friendlyName of the conference he has just joined.

This name is not present in the TCConnection parameters :(

SO I thought I would traverse the REST api for the correct data. Only to find that the CallSid entries do not match. For example:

User1 creates a conference called "conf" and invites/connects to User2. User2 gets connectionDidConnect with a CallSid in the TCConnection parameters.

I then look up the conferences for this account and see the conferences. I then look up the participants for the conferences and they are there. But the participants CallSid do not match the CallSid data I have from the TCConnection parameters so I cannot link them/determine the correct conference name.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I kept at this and found where I was going awry.

Basically quite often it takes a few seconds for a participant to come up in the participants list.

So I am now checking every four seconds until I locate the correct participant and this is working fine.